# No response on trying to post data to webservice

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am trying to post some data to my webservice but when I am testing it out in my device I am not getting error but at the same time nothing really happens, the tablet is responding just fine everything works but my webservice is not getting any data nor does the application show any error.

I have added some Toast messages to check the flow of logic and from what I can determine the app goes into the method to send data to the webservice and then just does nothing.

This is my code

```
//Method to post data to webservice

    public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Creating new user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.rgbpallete.in/led/api/signup").openConnection());
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String inputStr;
                while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                    responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
                String message = json.getString("message");
                boolean error = json.getBoolean("error");

                error(error, message);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

During testing the app executes this line `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Creating new user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and shows

> Creating new user

message and  then nothing happens. My phone network is a bit faulty so may it be that it is taking a awfully long time to connect to my webservice or is my code faulty?

**UPDATE**

I tried a bit more debugging and found out that the code flow dies on the line

```
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

Any one has any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with android but your java code looks fine.

What response code do you get when you call this:

```
urlConnection.getResponseCode()
```

I was facing some issues with sending a post data some time ago and I found really helpful to know what I'm exactly sending in a HTTP request. You could use [netcat](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/) to display what you are sending to service. FE.

```
nc -l 80
```

to listen for your requests on port 80 and just send a request to localhost or some other computer in your network that is able to execute such a command. All received requests will be written to your console.

If you will see that the request payload is correct there is probably some problem with webservice that you are trying to call.

EDIT:

I've tried executing a similar code against netcat and it worked fine.

```
try {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://localhost:3333").openConnection());
            //urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            String urlParameters = "message=blabla";

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i got

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_25
Host: localhost:3333
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 14

message=blabla
```

Comment: My workstation is windows so couldn't install netcat however the webservice is on a centos dedi tried to do netcat on that got `address already in use` error

Comment: you could also define another port which is free like nc -l 3333 or some other. Please be sure that alternative port is allowed in your firewall and url you are calling has that port specified properly like http://someip:3333

Comment: nothing happens when I launch the app, I don't think it is even trying to establish a connection. It gets stumped at `OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();` and doesnt even give any exception or error

Comment: Well, if it is not working with netcat it might be a problem with java code, but you can try reverse approach using curl to make a post request to your web service just to be sure that you are looking for a mistake on a right place. Have you tried if an exception is thrown when the url is bad? If you think it is causing slow network you cat increase your timeout also.

Comment: I have seperately tested the webservice it is working fine I am sure the issue is with the code. Let me segregate the codes within try catch and see if any exception is thrown